# Python script using NumPy for calculating an Option's Contract Greeks giving me no outputs nor errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have this Python script here which calculates the 1st order and 2nd order Greeks for a Stock Option contract. In the code you will see that there are seven different arguments that have to be chosen for the Python script to calculate the values. You can see all the seven arguments required in the script below.

Here the Python script should calculate and then print out the respective numbers for the Delta value, Theta value, Gamma value, and so on and so forth

Although everytime I tried to execute the script as done so below:

> python options.py 1 246.35 270 0.002 0.03 14 0.4615

I receive just a clean slate of nothing as a response and with no errors, not on my screen nor in an error log so I can't figure what's wrong. I tried doing a couple of tweaks but still nothing. I have no idea why I'm getting no output from it (or errors for that matter).

```
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt, pi,log, e
from enum import Enum
import scipy.stats as stat
from scipy.stats import norm
import time

class BSMerton:
    def __init__(self, args):
        self.Type = int(args[0])                # 1 for a Call, - 1 for a put
        self.S = float(args[1])                 # Underlying asset price
        self.K = float(args[2])                 # Option strike K
        self.r = float(args[3])                 # Continuous risk fee rate
        self.q = float(args[4])                 # Dividend continuous rate
        self.T = float(args[5]) / 365.0         # Compute time to expiry
        self.sigma = float(args[6])             # Underlying volatility
        self.sigmaT = self.sigma * self.T ** 0.5# sigma*T for reusability
        self.d1 = (log(self.S / self.K) + \
                   (self.r - self.q + 0.5 * (self.sigma ** 2)) \
                   * self.T) / self.sigmaT
        self.d2 = self.d1 - self.sigmaT
        [self.Premium] = self.premium()
        [self.Delta] = self.delta()
        [self.Theta] = self.theta()
        [self.Rho] = self.rho()
        [self.Vega] = self.vega()
        [self.Gamma] = self.gamma()
        [self.Phi] = self.phi()
        [self.Charm] = self.dDeltadTime()
        [self.Vanna] = self.dDeltadVol()

    def premium(self):
        tmpprem = self.Type * (self.S * e ** (-self.q * self.T) * norm.cdf(self.Type * self.d1) - \
                self.K * e ** (-self.r * self.T) * norm.cdf(self.Type * self.d2))
        return [tmpprem]

    ############################################
    ############ 1st order greeks ##############
    ############################################

    def delta(self):
        dfq = e ** (-self.q * self.T)
        if self.Type == 1:
            return [dfq * norm.cdf(self.d1)]
        else:
            return [dfq * (norm.cdf(self.d1) - 1)]

    # Vega for 1% change in vol
    def vega(self):
        return [0.01 * self.S * e ** (-self.q * self.T) * \
          norm.pdf(self.d1) * self.T ** 0.5]

    # Theta for 1 day change
    def theta(self):
        df = e ** -(self.r * self.T)
        dfq = e ** (-self.q * self.T)
        tmptheta = (1.0 / 365.0) \
            * (-0.5 * self.S * dfq * norm.pdf(self.d1) * \
               self.sigma / (self.T ** 0.5) + \
            self.Type * (self.q * self.S * dfq * norm.cdf(self.Type * self.d1) \
            - self.r * self.K * df * norm.cdf(self.Type * self.d2)))
        return [tmptheta]

    def rho(self):
        df = e ** -(self.r * self.T)
        return [self.Type * self.K * self.T * df * 0.01 * norm.cdf(self.Type * self.d2)]

    def phi(self):
        return [0.01* -self.Type * self.T * self.S * \
             e ** (-self.q * self.T) * norm.cdf(self.Type * self.d1)]

    ############################################
    ############ 2nd order greeks ##############
    ############################################

    def gamma(self):
        return [e ** (-self.q * self.T) * norm.pdf(self.d1) / (self.S * self.sigmaT)]

    # Charm for 1 day change
    def dDeltadTime(self):
        dfq = e ** (-self.q * self.T)
        if self.Type == 1:
            return [(1.0 / 365.0) * -dfq * (norm.pdf(self.d1) * ((self.r-self.q) / (self.sigmaT) - self.d2 / (2 * self.T)) \
                            + (-self.q) * norm.cdf(self.d1))]
        else:
            return [(1.0 / 365.0) * -dfq * (norm.pdf(self.d1) * ((self.r-self.q) / (self.sigmaT) - self.d2 / (2 * self.T)) \
                            + self.q * norm.cdf(-self.d1))]

    # Vanna for 1% change in vol
    def dDeltadVol(self):
        return [0.01 * -e ** (-self.q * self.T) * self.d2 / self.sigma * norm.pdf(self.d1)]

    # Vomma
    def dVegadVol(self):
        return [0.01 * -e ** (-self.q * self.T) * self.d2 / self.sigma * norm.pdf(self.d1)]
```

It would be greatly appreciated if some could help me out! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass arguments into a python script from the command line I would recommend something like `argparse`.  Also, a `@classmethod` to generate an instance of your class would be helpful/cleaner with `argparse`, in my opinion. At this point, when you run your script, it is waiting for you to instantiate the `BSMerton` class.

I am able to run your code in a jupyter notebook just fine.  I pasted your code as-is and added the following to a new cell.

```
test = BSMerton([1,246.35,270,0.002,0.03,14,0.4615])

print('Premium: {}\nDelta:   {}\nVega:    {}'.format(test.premium()[0],test.delta()[0], test.vega()[0]))
print('Theta:   {}\nRho:     {}\nPhi:     {}'.format(test.theta()[0],test.rho()[0], test.phi()[0]))
print('Gamma:   {}\nCharm:   {}\nVanna:   {}'.format(test.gamma()[0],test.dDeltadTime()[0], test.dDeltadVol()[0]))
print('Vomma:   {}'.format(test.dVegadVol()[0]))
```

Notice I am using the `[0]` index value when printing as you have returned a single item list with all of your methods. You could remove the square brackets if you don't want to generate single item lists.